# Javascript Performance Huge page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, performance

I have an Single Page App with lots of buttons (3000 with click event) and bootstrap accordions with nested accordion. The page can be almost 1Mb of size.

My problem is that sometimes after a while, the browser becomes unresponsive and crashes. I wondered if there is something I could do to reduce the chances of this occuring or should I change the whole design?

EDIT:
For example, I'm using :

```
$(".plus").click(function () {
        add1($(this).closest("tr"));
    });
```

Should I use :

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".plus", add1($(this).closest("tr")));
```

Instead?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a link to the site?

Comment: Do you use jQuery to add click handlers?

Comment: If the content is inside the accordions, you could always create/destroy the content on expand/collapse.  There's no point in having controls with events if the user can't see it.

Comment: Are you adding click handlers for each element or delegating one click handler on parent? Anyway, the information provided is not sufficient for any meaningful comments!

Comment: I can't link to the site sorry. 
Yes, I use jQuery to add Click handlers on each element and note on the parent.

Comment: Thanks Paul Abbott. It's a good idea. I wish I didn't have to do this though since it means I'll need to make requests each time there is an expand/collapse but I guess it's not that expensive considering the situation.

Comment: 1. Instead of create/destroy you could use attach/detach. This gives you reduction in dom-nodes but keeps handlers around to the detached nodes so you don't have to readd them on insert. 2. Also in case you add a lot of nodes to the live DOM (which will cause a lot of repaints), you could first build up your new representation using a [documentFragment](https://coderwall.com/p/o9ws2g/why-you-should-always-append-dom-elements-using-documentfragments) and attach that in 1 go. 3. As per above, don't add handlers to child elements individually, unless you absolutely must.

Comment: "As per above, don't add handlers to child elements individually, unless you absolutely must." You mean use .on() instead of click?

Answer (score 0):

I used the idea of delegating the click event to the parent and it seems to have improved greatly considering the number of buttons. But the main problem seems to be my design.

Thanks to [Sabithpocker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427146/sabithpocker).

I'll also try the options of attach/detach of dom elements that aren't visible.